# How can I find the item ID of a specific question in a Google Form to then update values from Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I would like to find the item id of a question from the last form response. Like the addon Form Ranger. This is so that I can update the list items read from a Google Sheet column.

The order of questions a user answers is as follows:

1. Which year group?
2. Which day?
3. Which club?
   4.Please fill in your personal details.

Here is a copy of the form to preview:
https://forms.gle/ob4Zh3ctgJcavQGW6

The question I need to keep monitoring is question 3 where the user selects the club they are interested in.

How might I go about doing this?

```
function onSubmit() {
  const parentFormUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1D39N98WeKvpj327unpZ5RFM6YIjzUstVSdfhEoYGwE0/edit'
  const parentForm = FormApp.openByUrl(parentFormUrl)
  var formResponses = parentForm.getResponses();
  Logger.log(formResponses.length);
  var formResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length-1];
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
  for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
    Logger.log('Last response to the question "%s" was "%s"',
               itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(),
               itemResponse.getResponse());
  }
}
```

I then need to connect the previous code to a code similar below which updates an item's choices.

```
function populateQuestionData() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var questions = form.getItems();
  for (var i=0; i<questions.length; i++) {
    if (questions[i].getTitle()=="Dynamic Question Title") { //OR ID IF THAT WOULD WORK
      var list = questions[i].asListItem();
      var sheetsData = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("YOUR SHEETS URL").getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues();
      var choices = [];
      for (var j=1; j<sheetsData.length; j++) { //Starts on 1 to ignore first row (with column name ID)
        choices.push(list.createChoice(sheetsData[j][0]));
      }      
      list.setChoices(choices); //Overrides the question choices with the array of choices we just populated.
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

I have realised the addition of toString() to

```
itemResponse.getItem().getId().toString()
```

Gets the ID of the question most recently responded to.

Comment: There is no need to add `.toString()`, `itemResponse.getItem().getId()` is enough.

Comment: Just for clarification, based in your last update it seems like the issue was resolved by adding that code line, correct?